# Obtaining a prediction in Keras

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, keras

I have successfully trained a simple model in Keras to classify images:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='valid', input_shape=(img_channels, img_rows, img_cols),
                        activation='relu', name='conv1_1'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv1_2'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='valid', activation='relu', name='conv2_1'))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv2_2'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I can also predict the image classes using

```
y_pred = model.predict_classes(img, 1, verbose=0)
```

However the output of `y_pred` is always binary. This also seems to be the case when using `predict_proba` and `predict`. My outputs are in this form

```
[[ 1.  0.  0.  0.]]
[[ 0.  1.  0.  0.]]
```

This works OK, but I'd like to have a probability percent for each classification, for example

```
[[ 0.8  0.1  0.1  0.4]]
```

How do I get this in Keras?

Answer (score 2):

Softmax might yield "one-hot" like output. Consider the following example:

```
# Input; Exponent; Softmax value 
20    485165195  0.99994
 9         8103  0.00002
 5          148  0.00000
10        22026  0.00005
------------------------
# Sum 485195473  1
```

Since the exponential function grows very fast `softmax` starts yielding one-hot like output starting from order of magnitude 1. In Keras [implementation of the `softmax` function](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/016d85c9e6d8a36fe7107e32752f6a9cd8d77c86/keras/activations.py#L6) the maximum value is subtracted from the input, but in the stated above case it won't make any difference.

Possible ways to fix this:

1. Make sure that input images are rescaled, so that pixels values are between `0` and `1`.
2. Add some [regularizers](https://keras.io/regularizers/) to your model.