# Keras model classifying well but predicted probabilities are always 1.0 or 0.0

Tags: classification, keras, conv-neural-network

I am using Keras to build a multi-class (3 classes) image classifier.
I trained the following model with a dataset of approximately 2000 images (1500 training/ 500 validation).

```
batch_size = 128
nb_classes = 3
nb_epoch = 25
img_rows, img_cols = 128, 128
input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)

Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 5, 5, border_mode='same', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 5, 5, border_mode='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Flatten()) 
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax'))

lrate = 0.001
decay = lrate/nb_epoch
sgd = SGD(lr=lrate, momentum=0.9, decay=decay, nesterov=False)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
              batch_size=batch_size,
              nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
              validation_data=(X_test, Y_test),
              shuffle=True,
              callbacks=early_stopping)
```

These are the figures for the training/validation [accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/se3ey.png) and [loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxbMV.png).

I achieve a 95% training accuracy, 92% validation accuracy and 94% on another separate chunk of images (aside from the 2000 of the dataset) that I have.

Therefore, the model seems to classify reasonably well. However, my problem is that the predicted probabilities for an input image (obtained with the function *predict_proba()*) are always either 1.0 or 0.0. 
Likewise, if I give as an input an image that doesn't belong to any of the 3 classes I would expect some low probabilities (perhaps higher in the most similar class) but I still get 1.0 in one of the classes and 0.0 in the others.

What could be causing that? It seems to me that there is no over fitting. Is there any issue with the model? 
Could it be that the images of each class are quite similar between them so somehow the model is quickly too confident on its decision?

Comment: Please see my answer to a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38192354/obtaining-a-prediction-in-keras/41833076)